# Settings.Bundle in an iPhone app 

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, nsuserdefaults, settings.bundle

I am trying to implement a Settings.Bundle based application. For that, I implement Settings.bundle in my application and I get output in the system Settings app.

[image]

How do I access this view inside my application? Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

iOS apps don't support showing Settings.bundle inside your app, but there's a great library out there called [InAppSettingsKit](http://www.inappsettingskit.com/) that will allow you to do that. I've used it in some of my apps in the past and I recommend it.

Another approach that I have taken is to define my own property-list format and code around it.